# Create event handler +=

Tags: c#, events, button, dynamic, handler

I am using this on my webform, to create dynamic buttons.

```
Button b1 = new Button();
```

I would like to get this:

```
b1.Click+=new EventHandler(OnClick);
```

How can I do this? I want that the event is created automatically, it could be done with pressing twice tab or something, but I forgot it...

Comment: Type b1.Click += [TAB] [TAB] and it should be autocreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my environment (VS2010 Pro or VS2012 Express), after you type the `+=`, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice to generate the event handler.

Comment: Ah, I thought it also created the += aswell after pressing tab.. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it works the same in both: as long as it's marked `event`, it should work. Maybe there's an option for it somewhere and you have it disabled?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean you want to know the signature for `OnClick` it would be:

```
public void CreateDynamicButtons()
{
    Button b1 = new Button();
    b1.Click += new EventHandler(OnClick);

    // Or you could simply do
    Button b2 = new Button();
    b2.Click += OnClick;
}

protected void OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is called when b1 or b2 are clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do tht by pressing tab twice after +=
or you can do it manually by

```
b1.Click+=b1_Click;
private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    }
```